# Searching nearest lower number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a much more simpler way to  if (searchNum - result) < 0, result will use the smaller value inside the array. for example 
9000- 10000 = -1000, since the result is negative, it will use the lower variable inside the array... 9000-7083 = 1917

This code is working but is there anyway to simply it?

```
Dim numbers(), arrItem, maxItem, result, searchNum, minItem

For x = 5 To 10


        'search number
        searchNum = Cells(x, 3) - Cells(x, 4)
        numbers = Array(1, 4167, 4583, 5417, 7083, 10000, 14583, 25000)

        'get max of array item
        maxItem = Application.Max(numbers)


        'loop through each array item
        For Each arrItem In numbers
            If Abs(searchNum - arrItem) < maxItem Then
                maxItem = Abs(searchNum - arrItem)
                result = arrItem
                    If (searchNum - result) < 0 Then
                        If result = 25000 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 14583
                        ElseIf result = 14583 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 10000
                        ElseIf result = 10000 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 7083
                        ElseIf result = 7083 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 5417
                        ElseIf result = 5417 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 4583
                        ElseIf result = 4583 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 4167
                        ElseIf result = 4167 Then
                            Cells(x, 6) = searchNum - 1
                        End If
                    End If
            End If
        Next arrItem
Next
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for the nearest lower value in a sorted array is what VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP do when using TRUE as the last argument.

The Array function in VBA generates a "Horizontal" 1 dimensional array, so you can use HLOOKUP to find the closest lower value to searchNum.

You just need to first check to handle the situation where searchNum is less than the smallest value in numbers which would throw an error. After that you can assign the result directly:

```
Cells(x,6) = searchNum - WorksheetFunction.HLookup(searchNum, numbers, 1, 1)
```